# Anime about a girl that likes listening to the chiming sounds of different rocks, travels to another world

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

I can't seem to remember its title, but it's an anime about a girl that likes listening to the chiming sounds of different rocks. She meets a boy that gives her his necklace, she goes with some old dude and meet the boy's brother in the other world..

What is this movie?

Comment: Hi and welcome to sci-fi fantasy stack exchange! Your question seems to be on topic, we could do with more details, please can you [edit] in things like when you saw this or the date it was released. Any other story or character details, like names or what made the 'other world' different.

Answer (score 4):

It's probably [Children Who Chase Lost Voices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children_Who_Chase_Lost_Voices) by Makoto Shinkai.
The main char is a girl who has a crystal radio receiver from her dad.

> Asuna Watase is a young elementary school girl who has been forced to grow up quickly ever since her father had died, while her mother, a nurse, works long shifts at a hospital. Asuna spends her solitary days listening to the mysterious music emanating from the cat's-whisker receiver her father gave to her as a memento

> One day, while walking to her clubhouse across a bridge, she is attacked by a fearsome creature and saved by a mysterious teenage boy who calls himself Shun. Asuna treats Shun's wound from fighting the creature and later they both listen to Asuna's radio. Shun tells Asuna he is from another country called Agartha and that he came to this place to find something.

Later she follows the boy and they both enter the country Agartha through a secret entry in a cave.